# Rails mailer template calculation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, templates, view

I am new to rails and am writing a daily report email template.

I am Outputting unique visitors, and calculating the difference between the 2 and displaying that as well with a + or - sign depending on if its positive or negative.

Is there a better way to do this?  Should I not be doing math inside the view?

```
Unique Visitors: <%= number_with_delimiter(@stats["unique_visitors"]) %>
<% uniquediff = @stats["unique_visitors"] - @stats["unique_visitors_yesterday"] %> 
(<% if uniquediff > 0 then %> + <% else %> - <% end %> <%= uniquediff %>)<br />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
("+" if uniquediff>=0)+uniquediff.to_s
```

`.to_s` turns `uniquediff` to a string, and the `("+" if uniquediff>=0)` bit evaluates to `"+"` if `uniquediff` is greater than or equal to zero, and nothing otherwise.. and you will already have a `"-"` if it is negative.
=]

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
<% unique_diff = @stats['unique_visitors'] - @stats['unique_visitors_yesterday'] %>
<%= "Unique Visitors: #{number_with_delimiter(@stats['unique_visitors'])} #{'+' if unique_diff > 0}#{unique_diff}" %><br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended to do logical stuff in HELPER(and it's what a helper should do).

```
# In helper, eg. application_helper.rb
def unique_diff(stats)
  unique_diff = stats['unique_visitors'] - stats['unique_visitors_yesterday']
  (unique_diff > 0) ? "+#{unique_diff}" : "#{unique_diff}"
end

# In view
Unique Visitors Diff: <%= unique_diff @stat %>
```

Comment: helpers are for all kinds of views, so mailers views can invoke method in normal helpers too.